# Yepnope js multiple files loading

Tags: yepnope

I have a list of js files:

- 1.js
- 2.js
- 3.js
- 4.js
- 5.js
- 6.js

etc

I want to load it on order, from 1 to 6.
If I do it this way:

```
yepnope({
  load: '1.js',
  complete: function() {
    next();
  },
});
function next(){
yepnope({
  load: '2.js',
  complete: function() {
    next2();
  },
});
}
```

I will be coding ridicules much codes.
Does anyone have an solution?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/issues/10#issuecomment-722029

yepnope does enforce execution order.  It will download all of the js files at the same time (to speed things up) but it will execute them in the order you provide

```
yepnope(['1.js','2.js','3.js','4.js','5.js','6.js']);
```